# Solving a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab, equation, nonlinear-optimization

I have about 1000 measurement which relates three variables to each other: `x`, `y`, and `z`. In other words, I have 1000 measurement values for `x`, `y`, and `z`. The relationship among them is as follows:

[image]

Could someone kindly tell me how I can find the coefficients `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` using MATLAB? If there were no interaction between `x` and `y` (`c3=0`), then `c1` and `c2` could be easily found by the backslash operator in MATLAB in a least square way (`A\b`).

Comment: this is just basic algebra...

Comment: Non-linear equations are not basic algebra @MarcB.

Comment: as yes. missed the `xy` portion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fminunc`, `fmincon`, or `fminsearch` and an anonymous function. E.g.,

```
fminunc(@(c) norm(c(1)*x + c(2)*y + c(3)*x.*y - z), c0)
```

for some reasonable initial c0 (problem-dependent). Fixed thanks to @TroyHaskin.

Comment: The function must return a scalar, so the objective should be `norm`-ed.  Also, [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) could also be used.

Comment: Good catch @TroyHaskin, thanks! Are you advocating `fminsearch` simply because the dimension of the problem is so low? I was using a gradient-based solver because the function is quadratic.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't advocating.  I wanted to include it since it is vanilla Matlab, and not everyone has the Optimization Toolbox.